# Sum and relates tables DAX

Tags: dax, summarize

I do have a table(1) containing the cost and the Project number, line number and item number and would like to get the cost summarized in another table(2) in a new column where im having the project number and project line also. The second table does not have the item number and does also contain budget figures on the more aggregate level. The two tables are linked on Keyz.

Table1

```
Item        Cost    PjNumb  PjLine      Keyz
------------------------------------------------------------
Q000001403  24,35   QP00032 11300102    QP0003211300102
Q000001405  24,35   QP00002 11100102    QP0000211100102
Q000001404  24,35   QP00003 11200202    QP0000311200202
```

Table2

```
PjNumb  PjLine  Budget  keyz
------------------------------------------
HG00057 1910    190000  HG000571910 
HG00057 111001  190000  HG00057111001   
HG00057 111002  0       HG00057111002
```

Ive done the following formula in table2

```
=CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[Cost]);ALL(Table1[keyz]))
```

I'm not getting any value out in the new column in table2.

Hope some one are able to help me. The Pjnumb and PjLine in table1 is retreived from a third table, not shown here.

Kr
Jan

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: `Summarize` produces a table, I guess you are trying to create a measure which accepts only scalar values. I assume you need a column in table 2 with Cost summarized by pjNumb and pjLine, if so format your question and add some sample data.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta, yes you are right. I've updated the text. Thank you. I'm new to this as you can see.

Comment: @JanBoldt, do you have one or multiple entries in table1 per each entry in table2?

Comment: @alejandrozuleta: I do have multiple records in table1 (many) that I wish to summarise per line in table2 (single)